# React render using state-pool

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables, render

Standard JS file:

```js
// functions.js

import cockpit from "cockpit";
import { store } from "state-pool";

const global_status = {
    key1: null,
    key2: null,
}

store.setState("status", global_status);

function update_config(data, message) {
    const json_data = JSON.parse(data);
    store.setState("status", {
        key1: json_data.key1,
        key2: json_data.key2,
    };)
}

export function get_config() {
    cockpit.spawn(python_script, superuser: "try", err: "message" })
            .done(function (data, message) { update_config(data, message) })
            .fail(function (error) { console.log(["spawn() failed: ", error]) });
}

// Initial loading of values
get_config()
```

In my JSX file I have this:

```jsx
// app.jsx

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert, Card, CardTitle, CardBody } from '@patternfly/react-core';
import { store, useGlobalState } from 'state-pool';

function ShowStatus () {
    const stat = store.getState("status");
    const info = stat.key1 ? "info" : !stat.key1 ? stat.installed ? "error" : "warning";
    const status = stat.key2 ? "Enabled" : !stat.key2 ? "Available" : "Unkown";
    return (
        <Alert variant={info} title={status} />
    );
}

export function App () {
    const [status] = useGlobalState('status');
    useEffect(
        () => ShowStatus, [status]
    );
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardTitle>Status</CardTitle>
            <CardBody>
                <ShowStatus />
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

When rendering this in Fedora Cockpit, it works, but only the initial loading of values (key1: null, key2: null) show. After get_config() is called, the status page never updates.

I've used console.log() and verified that "status" gets updated after get_config() is called, but the page does not render with the newer data.

CAVEAT: It's been some time since I coded in JS, and this is the first time I'm using React.

I've read the React docs as well as about 30 answers from stackoverflow about this, but I still have some issues getting around some of the Reactisms.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

update:

One of the variations I've tried:

```jsx
// app.jsx

function ShowStatus (stat) {
    const info = stat.key1 ? "info" : !stat.key1 ? stat.installed ? 
     ...
}

export function App () {
...
            <CardBody>
                <ShowStatus stat={status} />
            </CardBody>
...
```

Reason for putting get_config() in a separate file is due to several different pages may end up trying to update the configuration setup.

Comment: One variation I've tried:

Comment: The only other way I can think of right now is to have the python script save the updates to a file, then use cockpit.file().watch() function to see when the state has been changed. The python script returns a json stream, and I already have the setup to save to a file as well as return a json stream.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue... trying to recreate what you've done here, I believe you have to "subscribe" to the keys you want to have update your render function.

From the github readme:

```
    store.subscribe & globalState.subscribe
    
    If you want to listen to changes in a store you can subscribe to it by using   
    store.subscribe. it accepts an observer function. For example
    
    // Subscribe to store changes
    const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(function(key: String, value: Any){
        // key is the key for a global state that has changed 
        // value is the new value of a global state
    })
    
    // You can unsubscribe by calling the result
    unsubscribe();
```

Here is how it is accomplished in the test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { createStore } from '../src/';


const store = createStore();
store.setState("count", 0);

let testVal1 = 0;
let testVal2 = 0;

test('should update testVal1 & testVal2 through subscribers', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => store.useState("count"))

    act(() => {
        store.subscribe((key, value) => {
            testVal1 = 1
        })
        store.getState("count").subscribe((value) => {
            testVal2 = 2
        })
        result.current[2](count => 1)
    })

    expect(testVal1).toStrictEqual(1);
    expect(testVal2).toStrictEqual(2);
})
```